# How to solve $xe^x+e^x= e^4$?

Tags: exponential-function, lambert-w

How to solve $xe^x+e^x= e^4$?

I have come across this problem. But I can't solve this problem. I would be very grateful if someone helped me.

Comment: What does "solve" mean?  It seems unlikely that there is a pleasant closed form.

Comment: I need to find out the value of x. Sorry to bother

Comment: Yes, but analytically or numerically?  Numerically is easy...any method you try will work.  Wolfram alpha gives $x\approx 2.69344$.  Analytically seems hopeless, unless you are willing to accept solutions in terms of the Lambert $W$ function (which in this case is tautological).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is for you a very good introduction to [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which write or can rewrite as $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ shows explicit solution's in term of Lambert function.

Consider the more general case of $$a x e^x +b e^x=c$$ and apply the steps described in the Wikipedia page and get
$$x=W\left(\frac{c }{a}e^{\frac{b}{a}}\right)-\frac{b}{a}$$ Otherwise, only numerical methods will do the job.

Answer (score 7):

So $$(x+1)e^{x+1}=e^5 $$
which makes
$$x=W(e^5)-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

One might be interested in approximating the solution:

$$y=x+1$$

$$ye^y=e^5$$

$$e^y=e^5/y$$

$$y=5-\ln(y)$$

$$y_{n+1}=5-\ln(y_n)$$

Apply fixed point iteration with $y_0=5$ to get

$$y_0=5\\y_1=5-\ln(5)\\y_2=5-\ln(5-\ln(5))\\y_3=5-\ln(5-\ln(5-\ln(5)))\\y_4=5-\ln(5-\ln(5-\ln(5-\ln(5))))$$

Which approaches the solution.  $y_{10}\approx3.693443808$, and the actual solution is $y\approx3.693441359$, so an error of about $1.5\times10^{-6}$.